# Issue in implement table tools in Data table jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to implement export to excel from dataTable. So i download the plugin tableTools then trying to implement. i have called the following jquery Plugins.

```
./../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
../js/dataTables.tableTools.js
```

To show the row in dataTable i called the following ajax call function into data

```
function Databind(Pdestroy, fromDate, toDate) {debugger;
    var destroy = false;
    if (Pdestroy == "1")
        destroy = true;
    var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {
        sRowSelect: 'single'
    });
    $(tt.fnContainer()).insertAfter('div.info');

    var oTable = $('.datatable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        "bDestroy": destroy,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        'sAjaxSource': '/site/GetDetails?fromDate=' + fromDate + '&toDate=' + toDate,
        "bFilter": true,
        "aaSorting": [[3, 'desc']],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [5]}],
         "aoColumns": [{ 'sWidth': '5%', 'sClass': 'center' }, { 'sWidth': '10%', 'sClass': 'center' }, { 'sWidth': '8%', 'sClass': 'left' }, { 'sWidth': '29%', 'sClass': 'left' }, { 'sWidth': '11%', 'sClass': 'center' }],
         "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
         "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/Content/tt/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },

        "fnInitComplete": function () { },
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {

            $(".ActionPopup").fancybox({
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'titleShow': false,
                'scrolling': 'yes',
                'onComplete': function () { }
            });
            return false;

        },
        "fnPreDrawCallback": function () {
            $('.datatable tbody').html('<tr><td colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty"><img alt="Please Wait..." src="<%=Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Content/Images/ajax_loader1.gif")%>"  height="50" /></td></tr>');
            return true;
        }
    });         

}
```

But I am getting an error in the following,

```
var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, { // table is not defined
        sRowSelect: 'single'
    });
```

I have implemented all things in correctly. But why i am getting this error. Whether i missed any reference or library files. Please help me to find out the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(oTable, { // table is not defined
    sRowSelect: 'single'
});
```